# Hibernate with SQL Server incorrect sql

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I'm trying to connect to an SQL Server 2012 instance with Hibernate 5.1.1.

The problem is that the generated SQL queries are incorrect, the catalog name is inserted before the schema.

My configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
            <session-factory>
                           <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
                           <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://server_name:1433;user=***;password=***;databaseName=db_name</property>
                           <property name="connection.username">***</property>
                           <property name="connection.password">***</property>
                           <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
                           <property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
                           <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                           <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
                           <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
                           <property name="default_catalog">db_name</property>
                           <property name="default_schema">dbo</property>
            </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When executing an insert for example Hibernate generates the wrong SQL

```
insert into db_name.dbo.table_name ...
```

but it should be

```
insert into dbo.table_name ...
```

When I removed the default_catalog property the initialization failed with an error accessing table metadata, so that is necessary. The application has access to several databases, but it only needs to connect to this one. 
The entities are configured like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_name", schema="dbo")
public class Entity {
```

What's the problem with my configuration?